# how do I get rid of the message "Warning: you are leaving the hide and seek area"?

Tags: dishonored

My kid started playing this game without me about an hour ago. He chose to start the tutorial and then leave the area. Now there's a message that says "Warning: you are leaving the hide and seek area" on the screen at all times. We're past the opening scene, into the sewers and the message is still there.

I assumed that it would be a mission and I'd just be able to quit it but there's no option for that. It doesn't show up as a mission.

How can we get rid of it?

Comment: Have you tried starting over?  Might just be a bug with the tutorial.

Comment: @GnomeSlice maybe, turning off the tutorial stuff worked too but that makes the game a bit harder for newbs.

Comment: I'd suggest you try starting a new game before you get too far into it, and see if that fixes it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Start a new game and refuse to play hide and seek with the girl, or actually complete the game of hide and seek. Either will remove the warning.

Answer (score 1):

You could try starting a new game before you really get into the gameplay, or try disabling the tutorial.